# Gamekit No Network error only on LTE network

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, gamekit, gksession

I've built a multiplayer card game using GameKit, everything works fine unless a user is on an LTE network. If they are I get a didFailWithError No Network. Wifi, 4g, 3g, everything else works perfect.

Is there a reason the LTE network isn't detected or a way to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug for the initial release of iOS 7.0. After iOS update 7.0.3 the problem has been fixed.